# is it possible to display the relation between two tables in a MS-Access query design view

Tags: ms-access

Hi there fellow SO users,
it´s time to ask a question.

I am using the design editor in MS-Access 2019 to create a query a lot the past few weeks.
I can't seem to find a way to show the kind of relation between two linked tables directly in the query design view without entering the relation properties or switching to the SQL-view.

Searched for my problem but couldn't find any solution.

Any help is gladly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Saja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried double-clicking the line between the related fields in each table in the Query Designer (QBE)? This should load the relationship viewer. Also, the direction of the arrow heads of the line visually indicate the type (INNER, LEFT, or RIGHT JOIN). When you want to visually create a relationship, drag and drop the joined fields to create the relationship. This will create an INNER JOIN by default and you will need to double-click the relationship line to change to LEFT or RIGHT.

[image]

Note in the picture the arrowhead points from PostOffices to Cities, indicating a LEFT JOIN between PostOffices and Cities.

The FK relationship of the tables in the actual DB (SQL Server for example for Linked Tables) can be visualized and automatically generated in the Relationship viewer (the ERD Diagram tool in Access, located under Database Tools > Relationships). A query built from those linked tables only shows the properties of the local query (in the local access DB).

Comment: Thanks for your illustrative answer. Either I need glasses or ... idk. But the arrow head escaped my perception for many years now. I only saw and knew it displayed like 1 ----> ∞ for a 1:n relation between two tables. The same in the ERD diagram tool. Just the tiny arrowhead. Any chance I can change that to display "1--->∞"  instead of the arrow?

Comment: Hi, Saja. Great idea! To my knowledge, however, this is not possible.